# Change the font size in console output (IDE:MS Visual C++ 2010 Express)

Tags: c++, fonts, size

**SUMMARY**:

I am very very confused with the use of all the console functions. And especially with

```
SetConsoleTextAttribute
SetConsoleCursorPosition
GetCusrsorPos
ScreenToClient
ClientToScreen
```

I will be posting different questions for each one of these. As I am unable to get any kind of "HOW TO IMPLEMENT" information either on SO or on Google.

**Question**

How to change the size of font on the console output?(Specifically increase it and then return it back to normal after some text has been printed on the output)

**What I tried**

Looked into the help material available on MSDN about the console functions but they give only the parameters and some info about each parameter. Could not find any program where it was implemented.

**What I want help with**

Please give me the code to change the font size from what it is now(say 'a') to something I want to(say 'b') and then print something on the screen and then change it back to 'a'.

**Specs**

Windows XP SP 3
IDE: Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express

Comment: You can't change the font (size, style, family) of a console window from a program.

Comment: As Joachim Pileborg said, you can not do it programmatically. But you can install the TrurType fonts for console and manually set its size.

Comment: you mean there is not way? But i have read that the color can be changed.. why not the size?

Comment: [Console Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - this is what you have. `SetCurrentConsoleFontEx` is not available in XP. Console window is provided for your app, and the app cannot change font size.

Comment: @IceFlame - Admit that was wrong on this matter. Got lost on console localization few years ago (it can't print bi-directionally). But things changed a bit since Vista and using SetCurrentConsoleFontEx you can set the font. See how in Vista/W7/W8 - http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/graphic-class-visual-cpp-console-73619.aspx